# Python vs Airflow pymssql

Tags: python, airflow, pymssql

When I try to connect to a database using Airflow I get the error
'pymssql.OperationalError: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist'
What is strange I can connect using the exact same code in jupyter/python.
For reference this is a sample code of how I connect.
conn =

```
 pymssql.connect(
    server='server',
    user='python_script',
    password='password',
    database='test_data',)
```

Any help if appreciated.